# AS3: Symbol won't move to x and y on collision

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

```
function bucMove(event: MouseEvent) {
    buc.x = mouseX;
    buc.y = mouseY;
}

function OnEntFrame(e:Event)
{
sun.y += 25;
}

function hitTest(event: Event) {
    if (buc.hitTestObject(sun)) {
        sun.x = 259.85;
        sun.y = 142.15;
    }
}
```

I want to make the symbol "sun" move to the specific coordinates when it hits "buc" but it just stops when it collides with buc and continues to move if it no longer collides with buc.

Comment: You should probably also unsubscribe the **ENTER_FRAME** handler for the **sun** to stop moving after the collision.